# nvd3 is not a known element

Tags: node.js, angular, d3.js, nvd3.js

Using nvd3 with angular4

LineGraph.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LineGraph }  from './LineGraph.component';
import { NvD3Component } from 'ng2-nvd3';



@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
    declarations: [ LineGraph,NvD3Component],
    bootstrap:    [ LineGraph ],
    exports: [
    NvD3Component
  ]
})
export class LineGraphModule {
 }
```

The component file looks like

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Input  } from '@angular/core';
import { NvD3Component } from 'ng2-nvd3';
declare let d3: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'linegraph',
  styleUrls: ['./LineGraph.css'],
  templateUrl: 'LineGraph.html'
})



 export class LineGraph {
   @Input() name: string;


 }
```

angular.cli.json is

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "ng2-admin"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/sass/roboto-fontface.scss",
        "../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
        "../node_modules/ionicons/scss/ionicons.scss",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
        "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
        "../node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css",
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css",
        "../node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css",
        "../node_modules/ng2-slim-loading-bar/style.css",
        "app/theme/theme.scss",
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "../node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js",
        "../node_modules/chroma-js/chroma.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
    }
  }
}
```

and the html file is

```
<div class="graph-cont">
  <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>

</div>
```

Options and data has been supplied in the the component file . 
It continuously shows .  is not a known element . 
I was following this example [on it's offical website](https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3)
**Module name is ng2-nvd3** .
Thank you
 Errors after using 
import {nvD3}

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (7,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'version'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (424,17): Duplicate identifier 'Primitive'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (949,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'event'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1118,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'bisect'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1381,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'rgb'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1402,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'hsl'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1423,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'hcl'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1440,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'lab'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1460,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'color'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1740,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'interpolators'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (2671,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'csv'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (2672,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'tsv'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (3231,18): Duplicate identifier 'Padding'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (3372,5): Duplicate identifier 'export='.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/nvd3/index.d.ts (3404,5): Duplicate identifier 'export='.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/LineGraph/LineGraph.module.ts (4,10): Module '"C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/node_modules/ng2-nvd3/build/index"' has no exported member 'nvD3'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (7,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'version'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (48,13): Duplicate number index signature.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (424,17): Duplicate identifier 'Primitive'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (441,9): Duplicate number index signature.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (949,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'event'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1118,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'bisect'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1381,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'rgb'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1402,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'hsl'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1423,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'hcl'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1440,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'lab'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1460,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'color'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1489,9): Duplicate string index signature.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (1740,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'interpolators'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (2671,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'csv'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (2672,16): Cannot redeclare exported variable 'tsv'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (3231,18): Duplicate identifier 'Padding'.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts (3372,5): Duplicate identifier 'export='.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/typings/globals/nvd3/index.d.ts (3404,5): Duplicate identifier 'export='.

ERROR in C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/company/ng2-nvd3/node_modules/rxjs/src/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts (249,7): Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'XMLHttpRequestResponseType'.

Comment: Post your system.config.js

Comment: @Sajeetharan I m new to angular2 made and angular2 project .Is the angular-cli.json is the same as what you ask for ?

Comment: yes post it here

Comment: Looks like that's just typescript errors. What does your package.json look like? Maybe you're using an outdated version.